# How to nest standard lightning component inside custom lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to create a custom Lightning component and inside of it I need to output record details page and related lists. There are standard components in App Builder for this: "Record Details" and "Related List - Single" but I can't find a way on how to add it to my component. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you cannot include standard lighting components in the custom components as of today** unless you find a documentation from salesforce that says you can do so.

Your best alternative approach to make things easy on the development part would be leveraging [Lightning Data Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service.htm) in your custom components whenever and wherever possible!